# Set border color to glyphicon

Tags: css, glyphicons

I want to add a border to glyphicon font. For example, `glyphicon-heart` that has a red border and same color as the background. How can I do this?

`border-color: 'red'` didn't do the job. no border will be displayed.

Answer (score 22):

Basically the glyphicon icons are fonts and you can change the color of them just with the css `color` property. So, changing the color of the font, you will change the background. Now, fonts have no `border-color` property, but you can simulate it using `text-shadow`

```
.glyphicon{
    font-size: 60px;
    color:red;
    text-shadow: -2px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -2px black;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9suc171t/1/

Answer (score 3):

You could create two icons, one smaller than the other, and place the bigger one underneath. This could be a way:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart">
    <span class="inside glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>
</span>
```

CSS

```
span{
    font-size: 60px;
    color:red; 
}

span.inside{
    position:absolute;
    font-size: 55px;
    color:black;
    left:3px;
    top:2px;
}
```

[Here a Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tinmarin60/9suc171t/)

Comment: it's a good idea, but there is a better way using `text-shadow` ;)

Comment: @TomSarduy Sure it is!!

Comment: but I use your technique when is about having an arrow with pure CSS